# Which application is responsible for accepting passwords when entered in diffrent keyboard layout?

Tags: security, keyboard-layout, password, lightdm, lock-screen

I just noticed that when I'm prompted to enter my password to unlock the system, no matter what layout I choose (Persian or English) as long as I press same buttons that resembles my password in US layout it lets me in.

For example if my password is `salam` and I enter `سشمشپ` it will let me in.

But when I `sudo` something I should enter password in correct layout.

The question is which part of the OS is responsible for this? And is it really a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sudo` requires the correct layout, I suppose that the feature must be provided by the GUI. A very handy one, if you ask me. -- So, this is not really the OS but perhaps the window manager or the login screen?

More interesting is if this also works the other way round: Give yourself a Persian password, login with an active US keyboard layout and see if the system lets you in.

Comment: Persian password blocked me out of my own use. It seems that lock screen GUI just ignores layout.

Comment: Can you log in from the login screen?